# Requirement that terms not defined in a contract can only rely on the industry definition if "ubiquitous"

Tags: england-and-wales, consumer-protection

I had a reference to a case in english law where the judgment was that the supplier could not rely on the standard definition of a term within the industry, unless the other party was also active within the "industry" and wasn't a consumer, and the definition the supplier sought to apply was "ubiquitous" across that industry. Here's the catch - I'm 99% positive the word was "ubiquitous" but it might have been some synonym - my 1% of doubt is fuelled by the fact I now can't find that case!

I'm assuming it was an "unfair terms" "Unfair Consumer Contract Terms" case, but can't fully trust my memory on that either.

The key point I'm looking for is a conclusion that even if the understanding of a term is well-established within an industry (ideally the insurance industry, and even more ideally income protection / permanent health insurance), a layman consumer can't be expected to understand the term in that same way. I know that's a basic tenet of UCCTR, but I'm hoping for something more specific. FYI, the term is "self-employed" - the interesting thing about this is that the dictionary definition and the common understanding is someone who owns their own business or someone who works on their own account and carries the risks of running a business which he/she owns - but it seems the IP / PH insurance folks consider that person to be "employed" if their company is incorporated, but "self-employed" if it is not. My belief is that a lone director of a limited company who purely uses that company to market personal services (not as a director) will consider her/himself self-employed and would not naturally expect that an IP/PH policy would penalize a claimant based on the incorporation status of the business - and so if that is the intent of the policy it should be made absolutely clear in the policy terms, and the risks highlighted strongly.